# Pyodbc connection fails unless an unrelated import is made

Tags: python, odbc

This drove me crazy.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('conn str')
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8w.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

but (and I found this randomly after hours of debugging because another program with the same code was running fine)

```
    from loguru import logger
    import pyodbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect('conn str')
```

works as expected.

The first code block was working fine until a couple days ago. Just randomly stopped working. It's on a shared workstation so someone might have updated python or the packages.

What's going on?